# local host callback url something like "lvm3000.com"

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, omniauth

I'm trying to set up authentication on a local host and need a url, but third parties don't recognize localhost:3000.  I think I remember that someone found a solution to this problem by registering a domain that points to the local host ip address. The domain was something like "lvhm3000" but when I google that, it doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

Just to be clear, I'm looking for the callback url that I would enter on, for example, Twitter's site so that it would redirect to local host after authentication...

Comment: You could always use your localhost link as a redirect URL and it will work! check [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost/5141658#5141658)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

edit your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

and a line for example you want to redirect "www.server2k3.local" to localhost

```
 127.0.0.1 www.server2k3.local
 127.0.0.1 lvm300.com
```

Comment: thanks, but no. It was a web address that I enter, for example, on Twitter's developer page that sends their authentication back to my local host...

Comment: hmmm. i see. i think i encountered your problem when one of my project's domain is not yet ready. well, i hope someone can help you or if i have time i will help you to research also.